# Are potatoes considered a food that is fit for a king's table?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, bishul-akum

Are potatoes subject to the prohibition of בישול עכו״ם? Are they considered foods that are fit for a king's table?

This story I found quite fascinating and I wonder if it has any bearing on this topic

1589 - Sir Walter Raleigh (1552-1618), British explorer and historian known for his expeditions to the Americas, first brought the potato to Ireland and planted them at his Irish estate at Myrtle Grove, Youghal, near Cork, Ireland. Legend has it that he made a gift of the potato plant to Queen Elizabeth I (1533-1603). The local gentry were invited to a royal banquet featuring the potato in every course. Unfortunately, the cooks were uneducated in the matter of potatoes, tossed out the lumpy-looking tubers and brought to the royal table a dish of boiled stems and leaves (which are poisonous), which promptly made everyone deathly ill. The potatoes were then banned from court.
[Source](http://whatscookingamerica.net/History/PotatoHistory.htm)

Comment: Are you asking about a specific time and/or place?

Comment: https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040308030441W-37%20Bishul%20Akum%20on%20Potatoes.pdf

Comment: @DoubleAA no. Although you make a good point that it may depend on the locale. I did want to leave the question open

Comment: @DoubleAA this article looks great Thank you.

Comment: https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/docs/canada_state_dinner_2016.pdf (specifically Yukon Gold potato dauphinoise - which is basically potatoes cooked in milk and cheese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H/t @DoubleAA

From the [Kof-k](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040308030441W-37%20Bishul%20Akum%20on%20Potatoes.pdf)

> **Bishul Akum on Potatoes**
>
> A food which is eaten raw or is not fit for a kings’ table never has a
> problem of bishul akum.1 There is a discussion in the poskim whether a
> potato is fit to be served on a kings’ table. Some poskim say a potato
> is fit to be served on a kings’ table2 while others hold it is not.3
> If a food is served at a smorgasbord it is considered fit to be served
> on a king’s table.4 The minhag is that a potato is not fit to be
> served on a kings’ table.5 However, if a potato is made in a way that
> it is fit for a kings’ table, then that particular potato could
> potentially be a problem of bishul akum. Some poskim hold even though
> the potato is not fit for a kings’ table in one way of preparing it,
> since it could be fit for a kings’ table if prepared differently, the
> whole min of potatoes is considered fit to be served on a kings’
> table, and all potatoes would need bishul yisroel.6 However, most
> poskim disagree with this statement and maintain that one judges each
> way of preparing the potato separately.7 Accordingly, if a specific
> potato is prepared in a way that it is fit for a kings’ table then
> only that type of potato is a problem of bishul akum. This is the
> opinion followed by most kashrus agencies.8 (A sweet potato is
> generally fit to be served on a king’s table when cooked etc.
> Therefore, it would require bishul yisroel).9
>
> The previous machlokes has ramifications in regard to potato chips.
> Some say since a fried potato is fit to be served at a kings’ table
> one may not eat potato chips unless they have bishul yisroel even
> though potato chips themselves are not served on kings table.10 Others
> say since fried potatoes are not fit to be served at a kings’ table,
> potato chips would not require bishul yisroel. This is the opinion of
> the majority of the poskim.11

Comment: Thomas Jefferson served french fries at a presidential dinner in 1802. Does the status of oleh l'shulchan depend on the sitting king and his preferences or is it a status that once earned, is permanent?

Comment: @Danno good question